# Why is this simple audio code not creating any sound?

Tags: audio

I am learning how to generate sound using Windows and c++. I was trying to use a simple tutorial, but the code only creates silence. What did I do wrong? I tested with some print commands (which I removed) and the code seems to run to completion. Other sounds (from other programs, of course) play fine, and there are no error messages. I *think* the code looks right, but I am clearly not capable of judging that...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

// Sample rate
const int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;

// Frequency of the sine wave
const int FREQUENCY = 440;

int main()
{
    // Open the default audio device for output
    HWAVEOUT hWaveOut = NULL;
    waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, NULL, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);

    // Create a WAVEHDR structure to describe the waveform data
    WAVEHDR waveHdr;
    memset(&waveHdr, 0, sizeof(waveHdr));

    // Allocate memory for the waveform data
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = SAMPLE_RATE * sizeof(short);
    short* samples = (short*)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

    // Generate the sine wave samples
    for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_RATE; ++i)
    {
        float t = i / float(SAMPLE_RATE);
        float sample = sin(2 * M_PI * FREQUENCY * t);

        samples[i] = short(sample * 32767);
    }

    // Set up the WAVEHDR structure
    waveHdr.lpData = (LPSTR)samples;
    waveHdr.dwBufferLength = BUFFER_SIZE;

    // Prepare the waveform data for playback
    waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, &waveHdr, sizeof(waveHdr));

    // Play the waveform data
    waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &waveHdr, sizeof(waveHdr));

    // Wait until the sound finishes playing
    while (waveHdr.dwFlags & WHDR_DONE != WHDR_DONE)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    // Clean up
    waveOutUnprepareHeader(hWaveOut, &waveHdr, sizeof(waveHdr));
    waveOutClose(hWaveOut);
    free(samples);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's most likely because the 3rd argument in waveOutOpen is null. That argument  represents a LPCWAVEFORMATEX structure, which specifies the audio format. Check the hWaveOut value, it's possibly also null.

Comment: I'm new at this, what should it be??

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a WAVEFORMATEX structure before opening and playing audio (more information can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/ns-mmeapi-waveformatex ).

```
        WAVEFORMATEX wfex;
        wfex.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
        wfex.nChannels = 1; 
        wfex.wBitsPerSample = 16; //number of bits per sample
        wfex.nAvgBytesPerSec =  1 * 44100 * 2;//numChannels * numSamplesPerSec * numBytesPerSample
        wfex.nBlockAlign =  1 * 2;//numChannels * numBytesPerSample;
        wfex.cbSize = 0;

       HWAVEOUT hWaveOut = NULL;
       MMRESULT mm = waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfex, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);

       if (mm != MMSYSERR_NOERROR){
         std::string errorMsg = getWaveError(mm);
         //display the message etc
       }
```

In case of an error, you can query the mm variable and display an appropriate message that could help you identify the problem.

```
    std::string getWaveError(MMRESULT mm){
         
    std::string errorMsg;
    switch (mm) {
        case MMSYSERR_INVALHANDLE:
            errorMsg = "Wave exception: Invalid handle";
            break;
        case MMSYSERR_NOMEM:
            errorMsg = "Wave exception: Not enough memory";
            break;
        case MMSYSERR_NODRIVER:
            errorMsg = "Wave exception: No driver present";
            break;
        case WAVERR_UNPREPARED:
            errorMsg = "Wave exception: Unprepared buffer";
            break;
        case MMSYSERR_HANDLEBUSY:
            errorMsg = "Wave exception: Handle busy";
            break;
        case MMSYSERR_ALLOCATED:
            errorMsg = "Wave exception: Device already allocated";
            break;
        case WAVERR_BADFORMAT:
            errorMsg = "Wave exception: Unsupported wave format";
            break;
        default:
            errorMsg = "Wave exception: Unknown error: Code " + mm;
            ;
    }
    return errorMsg;
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I set the structure inside or outside main()?

Comment: @Henry Stone, it doesn't really matter where you set it as long as waveOutOpen has access to it.